# PHP exec() over UNC path on Windows

Tags: php, iis, permissions, process

My environment is Windows Server 2012 R2, IIS 8, Active Directory, and a file share.  IIS, AD, and the file share are all separate VMs.

I have a website, www.example.com, set up in IIS.  The application pool identity is set up as the AD user `IUSR_example`, which has "full control" permissions on the folder containing the site files.  The site files are on the file share, which IIS references via UNC path.

In general, the site works in that it can serve up PHP, ASP.Net, and ASP Classic pages, and the code can even create new files.

However, **I am having a problem that seems specific to PHP `exec()`**.  I've tried calling `whoami`, `dir`, and `ffmpeg`, and I get nothing returned from them.  Using Sysinternals Procmon I have confirmed that the executable never starts.

Weirdly enough, I *am* able to make the exact same calls with ASP Classic (using `WScript.Shell`), and it works perfectly.  I am also able to get PHP `exec()` working when the scripts are NOT running over the UNC path.

Here's what I've tried/found:

- When using ASP, procmon reports that w3wp.exe spawns a cmd.exe process, which in turn spawns conhost.exe and (for example) ffmpeg.exe.  The output file from ffmpeg successfully appears.
- When using PHP, procmon reports that w3wp.exe spawns a php-cgi.exe process, which in turn creates a cmd.exe and a conhost.exe.  A thread for ffmpeg.exe never appears.
- cmd.exe is invoked with a command line that looks like this:  `cmd.exe /c ""--the command to be executed--""`
- The command line for the cmd.exe process is exactly the same for both ASP Classic and PHP.
- In Procmon, the user is always reported as `IUSR_example`
- I've tried adding `2>&1` to the end of the command
- I've tried giving the IUSR to the "Replace Process-level Token" right
- I've tried turning off FastCGI impersonation and switching between "NamedPipe" and "TCP" under Process Model > Advanced Settings
- There are no errors in the PHP error log
- There are no errors in any of the Windows Event logs

Note that this is not specific to ffmpeg.  Any other use of `exec()` also fails.  Also, I would prefer not to use `WScript.Shell` from within PHP because eventually we will be using WordPress plugins that rely on `exec()`.

How can I further troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [suggested](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=71883) by user "pajoye" over at bugs.php.net, using `proc_open()` allowed me to successfully execute commands.  This in turn allowed me to use procmon to discover the difference between the way `exec()` and `proc_open()` work.  Long story short, I would call this a core bug in PHP running on Windows when the PHP scripts are on a network share.  Here are the key details:

- `exec()` defaults the current working directory to the path of 
  the PHP script, which in my case is a UNC path.
- `cmd.exe` does not allow you do have a UNC path as the current 
  working directory, and `cmd.exe` claims that it will revert to 
  the Windows folder.
- Although `cmd.exe` continues to execute and `conhost.exe` is 
  spawned, the original working directory still causes some 
  sort of problem, and the desired executable is never started.

So a simple workaround is to `chdir()` to a local directory before calling `exec()`.  However, there are a lot of WordPress plugins that rely on `exec()`, so in my opinion `exec()` should be agnostic to whether the PHP script is running on a share.  I will ask about whether a fix for this can be included in a future release.